# Performance issue with ItemsControl and complex ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, itemscontrol, expander

I've a performance problem with an ItemsControl. I've virtualized the ItemsControl using the following style

```
<Style x:Key="VirtualizedItemsControl"
       TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                  Focusable="False">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My ItemsTemplate is an Expander with another ItemsControl which ItemsTemplate is an Expander with a DataGrid (DataContext is a list in a list). [image: example]

When my bound data is getting more (like 100 entries in the first list and in each datagrid ~100 entries) the ui is getting really slow if i start to scroll.
I don't know why it's getting so slow.

I change the background color of each DataGrid cell if there are changes. That's why I use DataGridTemplateColumns.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
          x:Name="_container"
          Style="{StaticResource VirtualizedItemsControl}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Expander>
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock />

                                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <Image Source="trashcan-delete.png"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid Margin="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Content="Some text" />
                                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                                              Margin="5 0"
                                              Width="150"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              Text="{Binding Name.Property}"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Foreground="Black"
                                              IsEditable="True"
                                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.Children}"
                                              Background="{Binding Name.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}" />
                                </Grid>

                                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding ParameterBlocks}"
                                              Style="{StaticResource VirtualizedItemsControl}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Expander>
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index, Converter={StaticResource NumberToBlockHeaderConverter}}"
                                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                                   Foreground="White" />

                                                        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.DeleteBlockCommand}"
                                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                                            <Image Source="trashcan-delete.png"
                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <Grid Background="#E5E5E5">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <Grid Margin="5">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"
                                                                  Content="Some text"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsWaitingEnabled.Property}"
                                                                  Background="{Binding IsWaitingEnabled.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}">

                                                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                                               Margin="15 0 0 0"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                               Content="Some text"
                                                               IsEnabled="{Binding IsWaitingEnabled.Property}" />

                                                        <Xctk:IntegerUpDown Grid.Column="2"
                                                                            Minimum="0"
                                                                            Width="60"
                                                                            Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                                            Text="Some text"
                                                                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsWaitingEnabled.Property}"
                                                    </Grid>

                                                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}"
                                                              Style="{StaticResource StandardGridStyle}"
                                                              x:Name="BlockGrid"
                                                              Grid.Row="1"
                                                              CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                                              Margin="5 0"
                                                              MaxHeight="200"
                                                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}"
                                                              CanUserAddRows="True">
                                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Some text"
                                                                                    Width="200">
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel.Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                                                   Background="{Binding Channel.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}" />
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Channel.Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                                  Foreground="Black"
                                                                                  IsEditable="True"
                                                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.SelectedChannelList.Channels}"
                                                                                  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsPasswordProtected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOppositeBoolConverter}}"
                                                                                  Background="{Binding Channel.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}" />
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some text"
                                                                                Width="150"
                                                                                Foreground="Black"
                                                                                Binding="{Binding Value.Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value.IsDirty}"
                                                                                         Value="true">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                                                        Value="#FFDDA203" />
                                                                            </DataTrigger>

                                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                                    </Style>
                                                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Some text">
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Block.Property}"
                                                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                                                   Background="{Binding Block.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}" />
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <Xctk:IntegerUpDown Minimum="1"
                                                                                            Maximum="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.ParameterBlocks, Converter={StaticResource ListToCountConverter}}"
                                                                                            Text="{Binding Block.Property, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                                            Background="{Binding Block.IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyToColorConverter}}">
                                                                            <I:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                                                <I:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
                                                                                    <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.BlockChangedCommand}"
                                                                                                             CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                                                                </I:EventTrigger>
                                                                            </I:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                                        </Xctk:IntegerUpDown>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                                        <I:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                            <Commands:DataGridScrollToSelectedItemBehavior />
                                                        </I:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                    </DataGrid>

                                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                                                                Margin="5"
                                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                                                        <Button Command="{Binding DeleteEntryCommand}"
                                                                Content="Some text"
                                                                CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=BlockGrid, Path=SelectedItems}"
                                                                Width="120"
                                                                Margin="5 0" />

                                                        <Button Content="Some text"
                                                                Command="{Binding AddEntryCommand}"
                                                                Width="120"
                                                                Margin="5 0"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: First question: Do you have any binding errors?  Also, as a general rule of performance, try to see if you can change some of your grid column widths or row heights to static values.  If this is possible, and if it does make a noticable difference in performance, I would assume that your performance issue is related to size calculations.  I have had the same issue using ItemsControl and complex templates, and fixed a lot of it through static dimentions.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Virtualization tells the system to make the calculations as you are scrolling.  How is the performance of your application if you turn off virtualization?  Is it very slow to load the list.  Could that original load be better then lagging as you scroll?

Comment: Also, since your items have different heights, keep in mind that that usually means that WPF has to turn off virtualization, because there is no way for it to know the size of the scroll bar without knowing the entire height of the displayed items...  It has to render all items in the list to know the height of the actual list of items, so it can calculate the size of the scroll handle...

Comment: There are no binding errors. I started to use virtualization because I could save some seconds till the ui is rendered. If I turn of virtualization again the scrolling is working like expected (fast and smooth). I'll check if I can use some more static dimensions in my Grids. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok good.  Then disregard my 3rd comment.  I actually have a lot of difficulty understanding why/when does WPF turns virtualization off automatically, but I taught I would mention it just in case it was relevant.

Comment: The Expander style was the problem. I changed the complete style (based on the original which I got via Expression Blend) and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done; see my last comment. 
The Expander style was making some trouble.